# AJAX blocked when using cdvfile - Phonegap

Tags: ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

Doing AJAX from packaged files (eg location "**file**:///android_asset/www/index.html") works well, but doing it from local files (eg "**cdvfile**://localhost/persistent/TEST/index.html") does not.

I guess it has to do with the **same-origin policy**. Is there anything that can be done to make it work?

If I were reading files from the internet, I would set the web server to add some "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" headers, but here there's no web server. Using jsonp would work, but it'd mean changing the code in the server and in the app.

This is tested on Android 4.1.2 & 4.4.2 with Phonegap 3.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually using `toNativeURL` instead of `toURL` fixes the problem, as `toNativeURL` uses the `file` protocol instead of `cdvfile` protocol.

It also makes doing `window.location = pathToLocal;` work in Phonegap 3.5 (cf my other question [Cannot change location to local file eg cdvfile://path/index.html in Phonegap 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597969/cannot-change-location-to-local-file-eg-cdvfile-path-index-html-in-phonegap-3/25755810)).