# Cannot change location to local file eg cdvfile://path/index.html in Phonegap 3.5

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

My app copies files on the device using the `FileAPI`. This works well in Phonegap 3.4.0 and 3.5.0.

Then it opens an html file by doing `window.location = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/TEST/index.html";` (note that the path is not hard coded but uses something like `myDirEntry.toURL()`, and that both 3.4 and 3.5 give the same path).

This works well in 3.4.0 (tested on several versions of Android and iOS), but it does not work in 3.5.0 (tested only on Android 4.1.2 and 4.4.2).

When trying to change the location, nothing happens. The app stays in the current page, no exception seems to be thrown.

In both cases I use the `org.apache.cordova.file` plugin version 1.0.1 (the one available on Phonegap Build).

Has something changed in Phonegap 3.5.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason you simply need to use `toNativeURL` instead of `toURL` in Phonegap 3.5 (tested on Android):

- `toURL` gives me `cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Path/To/Folder`
- `toNativeURL` gives me `file:///storage/sdcard0/Path/To/Folder`

Using `toNativeURL` has the advantage to use the `file` protocol instead of `cdvfile`, so that there's no same-origin policy issue (cf my other question [AJAX blocked when using cdvfile - Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597950/ajax-blocked-when-using-cdvfile-phonegap)).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will not work if the filename contains any spaces as the toNativeURL contains url encoding. [That is the case with Xcode 5.1 and below as the data is stored in the "Application Support" folder.]

To get around this, use:

- decodeURI(NativeURL); in javascript
- filepath = [filepath stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]; in Objective-C